# Why the probability is concentrated on $\{0, \infty\}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

While I was reading Williams' "Diffusions, Markov Processes and Martingales" I found the following fact:

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian Motion. Then $\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_tB_t=\infty\right)=1$.

In the proof of that fact, Williams stated that if $Z=\sup_tB_t$ by Brownian scaling for all $c>0$, 
$Z=cZ$ in distribution. How this facts imply that the law of $Z$ is concentrated on $\{0, \infty\}$

Comment: $P(Z>\epsilon) = P(Z>1/\epsilon)$ and $P(Z>\epsilon) - P(Z > 1/\epsilon) = P(Z\in (\epsilon, 1/\epsilon)) = 0$. Does this help?

Comment: Also, $Z$ cannot concentrate at 0. Brownian motion changes sign infinitely often in $[0,\epsilon)$, in particular, a.s.

Comment: @JamesYang Since $Z=\sup_t B_t$ and $B_0=0$ clearly $Z\geqslant0$ a.s.

Comment: Of course!. Thanks @Jo'. That is the subtle observation.

Comment: @JamesYang. Yes, that its the second part of the proof in that book. Thank you!

Comment: @Math1000 that's right but Z = 0 is equivalent to $B_t \leq 0$ for all t which is a measure 0 event per my previous comment. So it's really $Z> 0$ a.s.. As a sanity check, if there were concentration at 0, you cannot have $P(Z = \infty) = 1$; you won't have a probability distribution then.

Comment: @JamesYang Your observations are subtle. Of course, if there were cocentration at 0, is so intuitive that we won't have a probability distribution. Yes! Thank you!

Comment: I agree that the distribution of $Z$ does not concentrate at zero...but $Z$ doesn't change sign (unlike a Brownian motion).

Comment: @Math1000 never said Z changed signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $R,c\gt 0$, using the equality $cZ=Z$ in distribution, 
$$
\Pr\left(\sup_{t\geqslant 0}B_t\gt R\right)=\Pr\left(Z\gt R\right)
=\Pr\left(cZ\gt cR\right)=\Pr\left(Z\gt cR\right).
$$
Letting $c$ going to $0$, we find $$
\Pr\left(\sup_{t\geqslant 0}B_t\gt R\right)= \Pr\left(Z\gt 0\right).
$$
Letting $R$ going to infinity, we find 
$$
\Pr\left(\sup_{t\geqslant 0}B_t=+\infty\right)=\Pr\left(Z\gt 0\right).
$$
Adding the probability that $Z=0$ proves the fact.